# Azure B2C prevent email address change after Home Realm Discovery

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, federated-identity, identity-experience-framework

I have managed to get the modern Home Realm Discovery (HRD) policy working with our directory and several federated IdPs. However, there is a loophole that I would like to be able to close. If a non-federated domain email is used, the user is then forwarded on to Local Account login with username (i.e., email) and password, **but the email value can still be changed, including to one using a federated domain**. Also, the Forgot Password dialog does not seem to pre-populate the email address so it can, again, be changed to any email address. Finally, even after verifying the email, there is the "Change Email" option.

I would like to be able to either

1. Lock in the entered email after HRD "failure" until the user
   completes or cancels the login,
2. Detect any changes to an email address in a known federated customer domain and send them back into the federated flow or...
3. Detect such changes and just error out.

Any ideas how to make this work? I did a little experimenting with the `readOnlyEmail` examples I saw but either something complained that it did not exist (like `ParseDomain`) or it was still rendered as a mutable field rather than read-only.

-GBS

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#hide-the-change-email-button

Comment: Kindly refer to this documentation link for more details: - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-authentication-for-federated-users-portal

Answer (score 0):

•   Yes, you can prevent the email id to change even after verification of email in ‘home realm discovery’ step by hiding the email from change or making it grey after entering it for verification email step. You can do this by adding the CSS entry below to your HRD enabled HTML page by customizing your HTML page template.

```
‘ <style type="text/css">
    .changeClaims
 {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
 </style> ‘
```

To customize your HRD enabled sign in and sign-up HTML page with the above entry, please refer to the documentation link below for detailed information. From the below link, download the default HTML page and modify it with the above entry in appropriate location, then save it in your repository from where you access the HTML files and modify the custom policy accordingly, i.e., with the ‘api.signin or signup’ content definition building blocks and save it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

By following the steps in the above link, you will be able to customize your HRD enabled sign in and sign-up page with also greying out the change email option. Also, to complete the prerequisites for it and referring the options regarding changing the email option, please refer the below link: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#hide-the-change-email-button

Comment: Changing the display is fine and all but I don't think it solves the real problem. What I really want to do is prevent any user in our directory who is in a Federated IdP domain from interacting with the system via local password, whether it is local password login or password reset.

Comment: Any user who is from a federated(other) domain/platform and performing guest user login or federated user login to access services or applications from that tenant in your tenant cannot change the password of identity in your Azure AD domain/tenant. They can only change password of their local identity, i.e., where they are originally registered.